# Extract correct combination of digits from string

Tags: android, regex, substring, replaceall, lastindexof

I am working on a method which **extracts** the correct **version number** from a String (for later comparisation if there is a new version).

The String which is being provided unfortunatly has **no fixed pattern** and can have **multiple combinations of digits**.

Below code parses the version number but if the string includes for example **build 50124** this number is **pasted after** the extracted version combination which I do **not** want.

It could also be that combos in the string are possible like for example v1.12 [build452] or  v1.32.856 (build 8754) but I already took care of that by **substringing the parts as of [ or (.**

The method in question:

```
private String extractVersion(String str){
        str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('v'),
                str.indexOf('[') != -1 ? str.indexOf('[') : str.length()).trim();
        str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('v'),
                str.indexOf('(') != -1 ? str.indexOf('(') : str.length()).trim();
        return str.replaceAll("[^0-9?!\\.]", "");
    }
```

I tested it on some examples but unfortunatly the result is not what I want, **sometimes digits are pasted behind the actual version number**, I refer to the **logcat output**.

Is there a 'better' regex or another way I can use to improve the method, so it extracts the correct version number?

Thank you for your help.

```
..
NewVersion = tempWatchList.get(i);
  Log.w("Versionnr", extractVersion(NewVersion));
  Log.e("Versionname", NewVersion);
..
```

Logcat outout:

```
/Versionnr: 5.131 //should be 5.13
/Versionname: somename v5.13b1
/Versionnr: 2.0..4 //should be 2.0
/Versionname: another name 2 v2.0.exp.4
/Versionnr: 18.01 //should be 18.0
/Versionname: somename v18.0-ALPHA1
/Versionnr: 7.2.42221..3634639 //should be 7.2.4222
/Versionname: another name v7.2.4222-1.L.3634639
/Versionnr: 5.0.220170112 //should be 5.0.2
/Versionname: somename v5.0.2 build 20170112
/Versionnr: 4.4.0.201701124401 //should be 4.4.0
/Versionname: another name v4.4.0.20170112b4401
```

Comment: `/Versionnr: 5.131 //should be 5.13
/Versionname: somename v5.13b1` Why are you reversing this? Please first mention/log what you have and then what you extract from it. Very confusing now.

Comment: Why dont you just compar the complete strings? You then will not know if it is a newer version but if it is a different version. Well if that is good enough..

Comment: Reversing? I only want to show what is wrong through the logcat.
I cannot compare the complete string as the string has no fixed pattern.
somename v1.3 build5421 could be provided as (new version) as somename* v1.4 build 42

Comment: Yes. So the strings would not be equal. So you would know they are different versions. (not newer or older). You also did not understand my comment about reversing the two log statements.

Comment: Hmm you got a point there but how would the complete string comparisation work then when there is a different filename?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is difficult in comparing some string variables?

Comment: If you know a better way to compare two strings for my intention, I`m all ears.

Comment: There is no better way to compare two strings. There are ways to compare two strings like for instance `string1.equals(string2)` or `string1.compareTo(string2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to extract versions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+([.][0-9]+){1,2}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(NewVersion);
m.find();
Log.w("Versionnr", m.group());
```

Comment: Thx but v4.1.0.9205 gives 4.1.0 as output?

Comment: According to v4.4.0.20170112b4401 example I've assumed that you only want to extract up to three digits packs

Comment: I see but that is not the intention.

Comment: So just change or remove the {1,2} part to match your intention.

Comment: Exactly, very nice. Thank you for the efforts.

Comment: may I ask a little additional question is it also possible to include coverage for versions like v6997 (without a dot)? 
I noticed some versions are also presented without a [.]

Comment: I guess you could use regex like this one: v[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)* and a substring method to get rid of that additional v at the begging

Comment: Great! Many thx. Maybe check for any letter combination in front of the version number. So A54857 or g4521 is also covered instead of substringing the 'v'. [0-9]+([.][0-9]+)* but does the job right till now.

Comment: I ended up using this [(Vv)+0-9]+([.][0-9]+)* and let it search in lastIndexOf the string

Answer (score 0):

This works with all the examples from your logcat messages:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+(\\.[\\d]+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(NewVersion);
if (matcher.find()) {
  String version = matcher.group();
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/P7lICp/1

Personally, I would rethink what you are doing.